# i created a pdf from word with an add on and now need to edit this pdf?

Tags: pdf, conversion, editing

i need to be able to edit the pdf found here:
[link text](http://www.polytechnicsolutions.com/SAMPLE_technical_screening.pdf)

is there a free app i can download to edit this pdf or save as word and use a word file instead?

Comment: PDF is a presentation format, not a content format.

Comment: without acrobat how can i edit this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) will convert PDFs to a number of other formats, one of them being RTF which can be imported into Word.

The [poppler tools](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) contain pdftohtml and pdftotext for converting PDF to HTML or plain text, which could be imported back into Word.

The free open source [AbiWord word processor](http://abisource.org) will import a PDF document as best it can into its own format, and you can export it into a variety of format, including MS Word format.

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) will import a PDF as an SVG image and allow modifications. Apart from Acrobat it may be best suited for this particular document.

However, as others have stressed, PDF is designed as an output format, and there is no good way to convert it to an editable format without risking the loss of quite a lot of formatting. Your document is almost all formatting, with relatively little content. None of the above will result in anywhere near perfect results.

Comment: ) then what can i do ?

Comment: @Hary I gave you four options to try. That's not enough?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I am *very* late in answering this. But this answer may serve others who stumble upon this question.

LibreOffice Draw can import PDF files. After that, you may place text boxes, lines, shapes, images, clip art, etc. anywhere you like. You can also edit and move these later on. To delete something, you may put a box (or text box) over it. If the original file is in editable format, you can edit and rearrange existing text as well. Otherwise, you can put additional text and drawings on top of the existing content, anywhere you like. You can edit multi-page documents as well. At the end, you may save the file in Draw format for further editing, export it to PDF, or both.

I have not tested it with PDF forms.

Answer (score 0):

as Ignacio Vazquez-whatever said, you cannot edit PDF. Its a postcript output. 
you always have to edit the source document (word) and re create the pdf.
That said, there are some tools that let you add notes, highlight, etc. 
I use Foxit Reader, its free and have many features. 
There are others, like Adobe Acrobat (very expensive), theres a solution from CutePDF (cheaper) and many others.

Another great tool is pdf split an merge (look at sourceforge.net)

I've used once a PDF to Word conveter, it doesnt work very good, but helps a little if you have to lost the source. I dont remember the tool name, but google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, if you use word 2007, if you install Office sp2, you can [create PDF's natively](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdownloads%2Fdetails.aspx%3FFamilyID%3D4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&rct=j&q=word%202007%20save%20as%20pdf&ei=ds4LTe3gB8Wynwfy56jXDg&usg=AFQjCNGcR1diK5wzTqw4vRtujxnHYw_Rig&sig2=vvKyXVl7O4ESxdNoKwf5gA&cad=rja), without using an addin. They are often much cleaner, as they make them as a text document, and not as an image that many others do.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard.  As others have said, pdf is more an output format, not to hold content, so it's not particularly editable.  It has a lot of layout tags in it and to read it takes a lot of effort.

That said, OpenOffice allows you to import a pdf as a drawing.  It's somewhat editable, but formatting will probably be way off.  It won't look like the thing you are importing.